# TextView text size differences for Galaxy S7 and Galaxy S10e

Tags: android, android-layout

I am testing my app on S7 and S10e devices. For both devices, xmls are rendered from layout_normal_xxhdpi folder. And I am setting my textview text sizes with dp. But somehow, texts are rendered in S10e are much smaller. How I can solve the issue?

Comment: you should use dimen for different size

Answer (score 0):

1dp has a different physical size in every screen, dp's take pixels into account. You can learn about it here:
https://youtu.be/zhszwkcay2A

You should use SP instead of DP. SP's remain the same physical size between different screen sizes. If you get variations of size with the same SP in different screens it is not made on purpose. Still this is the recommended way to do it.